# Display error message when autocomplete is fired if State is not chosen from dropdown

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have the following autocomplete

```
 $("#Postcode").autocomplete({
        minLength: 4,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: "URL",
                data: {
                    "stateId": $("#State").val(), "search": $("#Postcode").val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.Description, value1: item.Id };
                    }));
                },
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
        }
    });
```

I'm having a small issue in regards to when the user doesn't select a state from the dropdown and instead just types in a postcode, if the user hasn't specified what state they're in I want to display a message i.e "Please select a state" but I can't think of how I can include that functionality into the above code purely because #Postcode is a autocomplete textfield.

Can anyone suggest how I can do the above?

Added form as request

```
         <form action="URL" method="post">
                <div class="widget">
                    <h5 class="widget-title font-alt">Filter</h5>
                </div>
                <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="GlO6RMEwmiRYj9r_90enb74RLPDMQLu6wGcQXgLsiB57xsv9tolIYotzAMTAbzG5_IYxaaU6m8Vqi6mNyyf_upkQ7Wzvea7AVECYoZUtRH81" />                            <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SelectedState must be a number." id="State" name="SearchDetails.SelectedState">
                        <option value="">Please choose State</option>
                        <option value="1">Australian Capital Territory</option>
                        <option value="2">Northern Territory</option>
                        <option value="3">New South Wales</option>
                        <option value="4">Queensland</option>
                        <option value="5">South Australia</option>
                        <option value="6">Tasmania</option>
                        <option value="7">Victoria</option>
                        <option value="8">Western Australia</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="Postcode" name="SearchDetails.CityPostCode" placeholder="Enter a Postcode/City" type="text" value="" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-d btn-b">Search</button>
                </div>
                <div class="widget">
                    <h5 class="widget-title font-alt"></h5>
                </div>

                <br /><br /><br />
            </form>
```

Comment: is it a form ?
can you show me your html code

Comment: @Diptox added the form HTMl

Comment: thanks i will find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is it [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jejpjbr7/1/)

```
var selectedValue = null;
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#Postcode").autocomplete(
    {
        minLength: 4,
        source: ["2031","2032","2033","2034"],
        select: function (event, ui) 
        {
            selectedValue = ui.item ;
        },
        create:function()
        {
            $('.ui-autocomplete').unbind('menufocus');
        }
    });

    $("#formToValidate").submit(function()
    {
        if(selectedValue == null)
            return false;
    });


    $("#Postcode").on("keyup",function()
    {
        selectedValue = null ;
    });

});
```